# Using 'as' in the 'WHERE' clause in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use the parameter name given from 'as' in spark sql (spark 2.0.0) in the WHERE clause like so:

```
val ds = spark.createDataset[Int](List(1,2,3)) ;
ds.createOrReplaceTempView("VIEW")
ds.sparkSession.sql("SELECT count(*) as total FROM VIEW WHERE total > 1").show()
```

However, i am getting this exception:

```
cannot resolve '`total`' given input columns: [value]; line 1 pos 41
```

It seems that spark does not respect the identifier i have given the grouping column. Is this something that is currently out of scope of spark or am i just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `total` a defined column in `VIEW`, or are you trying to filter on the value of count(*)?  If you want to count and then filter on that count, the syntax should be something like:

```
select <fieldtogroupon>, count(*) as total
from VIEW
group by <fieldtogroupon>
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: You are correct. I forgot that the value of the grouped columns should be in the "HAVING" clause, rather than the "WHERE" :P . also i can do "select .... HAVING total > 1"